# Visualise a rails active record with something other than rails-erd

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erd

Hi I have to quickly learn the structure of a rails project that has been put in my hands. I am using Ruby 2+ I understand that there is a gem called rails-erd for back versions of Ruby and this generates a erd of your projects active records.

I have tried railroady and it doesn't seem to output what I want. Is there another gem that will do this while using Ruby 2 and up ?

Thanks

Comment: The `rails-erd` still works as expected on my Rails 5.1 application. Maybe you misconfigured it?

Comment: hmm interesting

Comment: @yeuem1vannam what version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: From `2.1` ~ `2.5.1` still work for me. Note that the `rails-erd` requires Graphviz, so please make sure that you install it correctly.

Comment: Cheers dude thanks for that